# How do I associate my iOS app with a particular website URL, for ScreenTime purposes?

Tags: ios, macos

I’ve noticed that, when using ScreenTime on iOS and macOS, the system knows that certain apps are connected to certain websites. Putting a limit on the Reddit app, for example, will also block me from visiting Reddit.com. Putting the Facebook app on Always Allowed during Downtime will also let me visit Facebook.com.

I’d like to associate my app with my website in the same manner, but I don’t know how the operating system makes those connections. I know the ScreenTime Framework is basically nonexistent so that doesn’t seem to be the answer, but it’s not just Apple apps that do it so it would seem to be something that developers have access to.

How can I associate my app with a particular website URL in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does specify how to associate a website and app. Its called **Associated Domains**

It is how it associates a website and an app in the case of universal links, handoffs, app clips etc. So it is the standard way to associate an app and an associated website in the Apple ecosystem. It would be also the same way how Apple manages app site association in ScreenTime too.

The details on how to implement it are documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains)

*Apple currently does not provide a developer API or documentation on the ScreenTime feature. (There's a little chance of Apple releasing an API for it later).*